# How to connect to Google Cloud SQL with go-sql-driver/mysql on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sql

I'm using the [go-sql-driver/mysql](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) driver in Go on App Engine to connect to a Cloud SQL instance like this:

```
import (
   "database/sql"
   _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

db, dbErr := sql.Open("mysql", "root@cloudsql(project:instance)/database"
...
pingErr := db.Ping()
```

but I get "**permission denied**" in `pingErr`.

Of course, I've checked my app is authorized in the Cloud SQL console under "Access Control" [per the docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access-control#appengine). I also tried adding a MySQL user with privileges and using `user:password` in place of `root` and even not specifying a user.

What am I doing wrong?

...

**Update:**

Per @Kyle's suggestion I tried an alternate driver [ziutek/mymysql](http://github.com/ziutek/mymysql) and it works with the following code:

```
import (
   "database/sql"
   _ "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/godrv"
   _ "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/mysql"
   _ "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/native"
)

db, dbErr := sql.Open("mymysql", "cloudsql:project:instance*database/user/password"
```

Guess it's time for a pull request on [go-sql-driver/mysql](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) if I can figure out what's going wrong! Any insights or experience appreciated!

Comment: I should also note I was able to connect with the mysql CLI both as root and the user I created so I don't think it's a DB setup issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a **versioning issue**!

If you look carefully, App Engine support was [added to the master branch](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/commit/7c08711297284b2769974565db6991fccd61b5ef) but [the latest release is 1.1](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/releases) and doesn't include it.

Instead of `go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` you need to manually `git clone https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` (master branch) into `$GOPATH/src/` and *then* deploy to App Engine!

[This comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-go/XZwBvrFCrQs/JV7MypsEaOgJ) from the author is what tipped me off and @Kyle's suggestion to try another driver (which worked) motivated me to re-read everything again - thanks!

Comment: is this the same case for go-sql-driver/mysql?

Answer (score 2):

The DSN (data source name) you're giving to `sql.Open` doesn't look like the one in the docs:

```
import "database/sql"
import _ "<some mysql package>"

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "cloudsql:my-instance*dbname/user/passwd")
```

Source: [Go AppEngine Cloud SQL Reference](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/cloud-sql/reference)

Edit: It looks like you're using the correct DSN format for your SQL package as documented [here](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/master/README.md#examples).  My guess at that point is that it's correctly connecting to the database, but that either the user isn't being accepted or, for whatever reason, doesn't have the correct permissions.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle - took me a few runs through to notice this from that doc: "The exact format of the second argument to sql.Open is driver-dependent; consult the driver's documentation for details." I did try some variations on it early but am now referring to the go-sql-driver DSN format.

Comment: @jkoreska Have you tried another driver to figure out whether it's a driver issue or a database setup or username/password issue?

Comment: No I haven't yet but that's an excellent suggestion! I assumed it was good to go from this: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/commit/7c08711297284b2769974565db6991fccd61b5ef

Comment: Lovely - it works with `github.com/ziutek/mymysql`! Like so: `sql.Open("mymysql", "cloudsql:project:instance*database/user/password")`