# bad HTTP response from Google CloudSQL

Tags: mysql, go, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying hand at Google Cloud SQL using go-sql-driver. I'm stuck here I don't know whats wrong here. This error is totally unknown for me.

```
package hello

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "database/sql"
  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func init() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  const dbUserName = "userName"
  const dbPassword = "password"
  const dbIP = "123.123.231.123"

  db, err := sql.Open("mysql",  dbUserName+":"+dbPassword+"@"+dbIP+":3306/user")


  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error()) 
  }


  // Query the name 
  rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM user")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error()) 
  }

  fmt.Println(rows)

  defer db.Close()
}
```

ERROR:

```
 the runtime process gave a bad HTTP response: ''

 2015/04/12 09:23:36 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:50091: Default addr  for network '173.194.106.126:3306' unknown
 goroutine 6 [running]:
 net/http.funcÂ·011()
 /private/var/folders/00/0v42r000h01000cxqpysvccm003chb/T/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/net/http/server.go:1130 +0xbb
 main37089.handler(0x5ad1e0, 0xc208044280, 0xc2080331e0)
```

Any ideas. Looking at source of go-sql-driver source maybe I should set a default address?

Comment: What happens if you add the tcp protocol in the DSN?  e.g. User:pass@tcp(123.123.123.123:3306)/dbname ? What happens if you don't specify the dbname?

Comment: Don't you need `cloudsql:instance-name*...` to expose the access of database? Read [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/cloud-sql/reference) and it may be useful.

Comment: @Anzel I tried doing that too. It won't work on dev i.e. my local. It works when I upload it to app engine.

Comment: @cflewis with protocol it says bad connection.

Comment: @user2215912, I remember on cloudsql you may need to whitelist your IPs (so you need to include your local dev IP), otherwise the connection will be refused.

Comment: @Anzel I did that too

Comment: @user2215912, I am also new to Go so I'm afraid I cannot help you further as I have cloudsql experience with Python but not with Go.

Comment: You may be interested in this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368363/how-to-connect-to-google-cloud-sql-with-go-sql-driver-mysql-on-app-engine), if you haven't read it already

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your error has anything to do with the SQL driver. If you read the message it is arising from the http packages server code, not from anything having to do with your SQL connection/reading/writing ect. Looking at your code and comparing it to basic examples I'm fairly sure your error is due to lack of this line in main; `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)`

Basically, change your main to

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

And that error will probably go away. Disclaimer; that doesn't mean your program will magically work, only that it will *never* work without it.