# Connect Google App Engine with Google Cloud Storage in flexible environment

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I want to connect from my GAE app to my Google Cloud MySQL instance. I am using the `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` driver and I followed the steps specified in the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/using-cloud-sql). Apparently I can connect to the database without an error but when I want to make a request I get `driver: bad connection` and `packets.go:33: unexpected EOF`. I authorised both my local IP address and the GAE app to access my database and I can connect to it from my local machine and the mysql client without a problem. I have already tried setting up my app in the standard environment and followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368363/how-to-connect-to-google-cloud-sql-with-go-sql-driver-mysql-on-app-engine) but it didn't work either.

That is my Go code with which I connect to the database:

```
host := os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
user := os.Getenv("DB_USER")
pwd := os.Getenv("DB_PWD")
connectionInfo := fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v@tcp(%v:3306)/mobile_data?parseTime=true", user, pwd, host)
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", connectionInfo)
```

And this is my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: go
vm: true
env_variables:
    "DB_HOST": "[Google Cloud MySQL Instance IPv4]"
    "DB_USER": "[User]"
    "DB_PWD": "[Password]"
```

Any tip or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you connect to first generation or second generation cloud sql instance? If it's second generation, you should use cloud sql proxy: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#instanceaccess

Comment: I connected with the first generation instance. Ah, in the link you send me they state that access from the app engine flexible environment to a first generation instance is not supported. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#instanceaccess) link states that instance-level access between the app engine flexible environment and a First Generation Cloud SQL instance is not supported yet. If you want to connect to a Second Generation Cloud SQL you would have to use the Cloud SQL Proxy.
Thanks to @Tianzhou for pointing me to the link.